# Can't set firebase timestamp with unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

```
//save data
private void writeNewUser(string userId, string name, string email)
{
    User user = new User(name, email);
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(user);
    //save user data with json
    mDatabaseRef.Child("users").Child(userId).SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
    //save time
    mDatabaseRef.Child("time").SetValueAsync(Firebase.Database.ServerValue.Timestamp);

    Debug.Log("firebase DB write done");
    t_debug.text = "firebase DB write done";

}
```

User data save success, but have error with timestamp.
How can I save timestmap to server? 
I searched many post, but most are java or android native, and I can't understand it.

Thank you.

[userdata success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bk8L.png)

[error with timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk6ob.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. problem was unity's Json builder doesn't work with dictionary.

[Can't set firebase timestamp with unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843598/cant-set-firebase-timestamp-with-unity)

was hint.

I just added stings to end of built Json string, and now save time nicely.

```
//save data
private void writeNewUser(string userId, string name, string email)
{
    User user = new User(name, email);
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(user);
    Debug.Log("original");
    Debug.Log(json);

    json = json.Substring(0, json.Length-1);
    Debug.Log("cutted");
    Debug.Log(json);

    string timestampAdd = @" , ""timestamp"": {"".sv"" : ""timestamp""} } ";
    Debug.Log("adder");
    Debug.Log(timestampAdd);
    json = json + timestampAdd;
    Debug.Log("added");
    Debug.Log(json);

    //save user data with json
    mDatabaseRef.Child("users").Child(userId).SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);

    Debug.Log("firebase DB write done");
    t_debug.text = "firebase DB write done";

}
```